# How to send an AJAX request for PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

have tried to send a message for hours, the HTML:

```
<div  id="contactform">
<div id="contact_results"></div>
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="contact_me.php">

<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text"  name="telephone">    
<input type="text" name="email">
<textarea  rows="6" name="message"></textarea>    
<input type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit_btn">

</form>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
//Rest of your code

    var proceed = true;
    //simple validation at client's end
    //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
    $("#contactform input[required=true], #contactform textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
        }
        //check invalid email
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
        }   
    });

    if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
    {
        //get input field values data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'name'      : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
            'email' : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
            'telephone' : $('input[name=telephone]').val(), 
            'msg'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val()
        };

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){  
            if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                //reset values in all input fields
                $("#contactform  input[required=true], #contactform textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
                $("#contactform .white-spacing").slideUp(); //hide form after success
            }
            $("#contactform #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
    }
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#contactform  input[required=true], #contactform textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
    $(this).css('border-color',''); 
    $("#result").slideUp();
});
});
```

The contact_me.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$to_email       = "myemail@yahoo.com"; 

//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
        'type'=>'error', 
        'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
} 

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$name       = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email      = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$telephone  = filter_var($_POST["telephone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//additional php validation
if(strlen($name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($telephone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
    die($output);
}

//email body
$message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$name."\r\nEmail : ".$email."\r\nPhone Number :". $telephone;

//proceed with PHP email.
$headers = 'From: '.$name.'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

if(!$send_mail)
{
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
    die($output);
}
}
    ?>
```

How can I get the site to send the AJAX request? It keeps getting stuck in the first PHP code, and returns 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'. I am running on the basic GoDaddy Linux server.

Thanks for all the JS experts!

Comment: For AJAX, you wouldn't have to use `method="POST" action="contact_me.php"` for form submission. It should all be taken care in your JavaScript.

Comment: Echo `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` and see if you get the right thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending the form on click on the button #submit_btn. You need to prevent the default event for the submit button of the form.

With $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] you are checking if the file is accessed via ajax request and because you are not sending it via ajax you get the error 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'.

So to prevent the form from actually being submitted on submit button click you need to add

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    //Rest of your code

});
```

You can also try it this way

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    //Rest of your code
});
```

You can run your code on form submit instead of the submit button click.

Comment: I added the code on top of my JS, tested and still nothing. How does the full JS look on your end? I have it before my closing body tag.

Comment: Try it with the second option I added in the answer. Work with the form submit event. prevent it, and send the form with ajax.

Comment: thanks - that solved the sending, now I see it is not getting the values in the textarea, it keeps outputting 'Too short message'

Comment: I tried removing the strlen checker, and now nothing happens on Submit. @bojan,  I am more than happy to pay you for your effort, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: You don't need to pay me while we are here on SO. As for your problem, try to print out $message. See what is stored in that variable :)

Comment: ha! as a matter of fact I am flying to Skopje in 2 weeks, maybe you will accept payment in beer? :) I have uploaded the form on here if you have the time to take a look: http://chcdigital.com/contact/

Comment: Ok I know why it is printing that, as you see in your post_data you are sending msg not message :D Change it to message and it will work :) Write me when you are in town and maybe we can drink that beer :)